# Dual boot not working properly

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, windows-10

I tried to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

1. I shrank the drives from Windows using EaseUS because the diskmgmt.msc didn't let me shrink the drives beyond a certain range.
2. I partitioned ubuntu to three partitions in the SSD drive. I have two drives and one of them is an SSD. The efi partition, the root partition, and the swap partition as you will see in the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

When I restart, the computer boots to Ubuntu automatically, rather then taking me to the grub menu. I tried updating grub, but it didn't work.
Also the BIOS is showing two SSD disks rather than only one:

Before dual boot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulAZR.jpg]

After dual boot:

[image]

Only one with Ubuntu works and the other shows an error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulAZR.jpg]

Comment: yea but my computer boots to Ubuntu not windows 10 ! ... can you give me a solution for that !

Comment: Your Windows install is on a MBR partitioned drive, since you have an extended partition. Then Windows must be in BIOS boot mode, not UEFI. But Ubuntu is in UEFI boot mode. You must have both installs in same boot mode if on same drive. With BIOS boot flag must be on Windows bootable partiiton and with UEFI boot flag is on ESP. But you cannot have two boot flags. Move boot flag back to sda1 and boot hard drive to boot Windows. Or re-install Windows in UEFI boot mode after full backup.

Comment: am really sorry for being an absolute noob, can you give a more simplified explanation !  i don't know how to move the boot flag to sd1 ?

Comment: i tried to change to the boot mode in the bios ...  when i changed it to UEFI , only the hard drive with the Ubuntu appeared, so i think that confirms what you said !! but i'm still don't know what to do !

Comment: i tried to reinstall ubunutu from "usb key" instead of "UEFI usb key" , and it worked .. now when i start the computer it takes me to the grub menu ! .. thanks fa lot for the help :)